# Graphics corruption inside some application's window

Tags: graphics, multiple-monitors, xorg, plasma-5, screen-corruption

I have 3 monitors :

- my laptop's screen
- a screen connected to the HDMI port
- a screen connected by HDMI through an USB-C hub.

**I sometimes experience graphics corruption inside some application's window**, like parts of the window not refreshing, flickering, or showing a part of another app. Sometimes this can be fixed by clicking inside the window or resizing it, sometimes I have to close the app and open it again. This is not limited to any specific application, although it seems to often happen with Geany or CherryTree.

Here is an example with CherryTree after I tried to resize it a few times :
[image: example of bug behaviour]

**Hardware :** Lenovo Thikpad P14s with hybrid graphics (integrated Intel GPU and additional nVidia CPU). I used `sudo prime-select intel` to set it to use only the integrated GPU, in order to reduce heating and other problems I had when connecting and disconnecting monitors.

**Software :** Ubuntu 23.04 with KDE Plasma 5.27.4 on Xorg 1.21.1.7

There's nothing in my `.xsession-errors` or `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` when this happens.

How should I go about debugging this ? Even though I am an experimented Linux user and system administrator, I don't even know where to begin troubleshooting, and what could be at fault here : the application, plasma, xorg, the video driver...

As far as I know, this never happens when the external monitors are not connected.

**Additionnal info :** output of `sudo inxi -Fxxx`, shortened to relevant info :

```
System:
  Host: sylvain-thinkpad Kernel: 6.2.0-20-generic arch: x86_64 bits: 64
    compiler: N/A Desktop: KDE Plasma v: 5.27.4 wm: kwin_x11 dm: SDDM
    Distro: Ubuntu 23.04 (Lunar Lobster)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20S40006FR v: ThinkPad P14s Gen 1
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] vendor: Lenovo driver: i915
    v: kernel arch: Gen-9.5 ports: active: DP-3,HDMI-A-2,eDP-1 empty: DP-1,
    DP-2, DP-4, HDMI-A-1 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:9b41 class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP108GLM [Quadro P520] vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A
    arch: Pascal pcie: speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 4 bus-ID: 2d:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:1d34
    class-ID: 0302
  Device-3: Chicony Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 1-8:4 chip-ID: 04f2:b6d9 class-ID: 0e02 serial: 0001
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.8
    compositor: kwin_x11 driver: X: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa
    dri: iris gpu: i915 display-ID: :0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 7040x1440 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 1862x381mm (73.31x15.00")
    s-diag: 1901mm (74.83")
  Monitor-1: DP-3 mapped: DP-1-1 pos: top-right model: Idek Iiyama PL2791Q
    serial: 1153902021080 res: 2560x1440 hz: 60 dpi: 109
    size: 597x336mm (23.5x13.23") diag: 686mm (27") modes: max: 2560x1440
    min: 640x480
  Monitor-2: HDMI-A-2 mapped: HDMI-2 pos: top-center
    model: Idek Iiyama PL2791Q serial: 1153902221311 res: 2560x1440 hz: 60
    dpi: 109 size: 597x336mm (23.5x13.23") diag: 686mm (27") modes:
    max: 2560x1440 min: 640x480
  Monitor-3: eDP-1 pos: primary,bottom-l model: AU Optronics 0x403d
    res: 1920x1080 hz: 60 dpi: 158 size: 309x174mm (12.17x6.85")
    diag: 355mm (14") modes: 1920x1080
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.2 renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2)
    direct-render: Yes
```

**EDIT:** Still having the same problem with Geany and CherryTree, six months later and after reinstalling Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, with `prime-select on-demand`

Current system info :

```
System:
  Host: sylvain-laptop Kernel: 6.5.0-1009-oem x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A
    Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.27.10 wm: kwin_x11 dm: SDDM
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 20S40006FR v: ThinkPad P14s Gen 1
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] vendor: Lenovo driver: i915
    v: kernel ports: active: DP-4,HDMI-A-2,eDP-1
    empty: DP-1, DP-2, DP-5, HDMI-A-1 bus-ID: 00:02.0 chip-ID: 8086:9b41
    class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: NVIDIA GP108GLM [Quadro P520] driver: N/A pcie: speed: 8 GT/s
    lanes: 4 bus-ID: 2d:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:1d34 class-ID: 0302
  Device-3: Chicony Integrated Camera type: USB driver: uvcvideo
    bus-ID: 1-8:5 chip-ID: 04f2:b6d9 class-ID: 0e02 serial: 0001
  Display: server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 compositor: kwin_x11 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 display-ID: :0
    screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 7040x1440 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 1862x381mm (73.3x15.0")
    s-diag: 1901mm (74.8")
  Monitor-1: DP-1-1 pos: right res: 2560x1440 hz: 60 dpi: 109
    size: 597x336mm (23.5x13.2") diag: 685mm (27")
  Monitor-2: HDMI-2 mapped: HDMI-A-2 pos: center model: Idek Iiyama PL2791Q
    serial: 1153902221311 res: 2560x1440 hz: 60 dpi: 109
    size: 597x336mm (23.5x13.2") diag: 686mm (27") modes: max: 2560x1440
    min: 640x480
  Monitor-3: eDP-1 pos: primary,left model: AU Optronics res: 1920x1080
    hz: 60 dpi: 158 size: 309x174mm (12.2x6.9") diag: 355mm (14")
    modes: 1920x1080
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 direct render: Yes
```